# What is the easiest way to integrate Azure AD B2C with Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

Previously I have been using `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(..)` to initiate authentication flow with social identity providers.

More recently I set up Azure B2C - I have used `Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(..)` to initiate authentication in browser and obtain a JSON web token:

Can I use the JSON web token from B2C to authenticate with the Azure App Service?

Can I use the following to authenticate with the Azure App service?

```
MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, [JWT HERE])
```

Is there an easier way to authenticate with Azure App Service + Azure B2C?

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: There are quite a few [examples available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples), I'm guessing your scenario is in there?

Comment: Any process now?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is [Integrating Azure Active Directory B2C with Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app).

The method  `CreateOptionsFromPolicy` will take the Policy name as input parameter and will return an object of type `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`, This object is responsible for controlling the `OpenID` Connect middleware.

The  `TokenValidationParameters` is used to store the information needed to validate the tokens, we only need to change 2 settings here, the  `NameClaimType` and the  `SaveSigninToken` .

```
private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
{
    return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
     {
         // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
         // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
         MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
         AuthenticationType = policy,
         // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config  
         ClientId = clientId,
         RedirectUri = redirectUri,
         PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
         Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
         {
             AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed
         },
         Scope = "openid",
         ResponseType = "id_token",
         // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
         TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            SaveSigninToken = true //important to save the token in boostrapcontext
         }
    };
}
```

If you want to Integrate Azure AD B2C with Web App, you could refer to this [article](http://bitoftech.net/2016/08/31/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-mvc-web-app/) and this [one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/06/22/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/).